# How to define a strongly typed form with a recursive field in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I would like to define a strongly typed form with a recursive field:

```js
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export interface ICodeSystemConceptForm {
  code: FormControl<string>;
  display: FormControl<string>;
  definition: FormControl<string>;
  concept: FormArray<FormControl<ICodeSystemConceptForm>>;
}
```

I have a function to create and return the form. Notice the `concept` field is recursive:

```js
export const initCodeSystemConceptForm = (concept?: fhir4.CodeSystemConcept, codeDisabled = false): ICodeSystemConceptForm => {
  return {
    code: new FormControl(
      {
        value: concept?.code || '',
        disabled: codeDisabled,
      },
      [ Validators.required ]
    ),
    display: new FormControl(concept?.display || ''),
    definition: new FormControl(concept?.definition || ''),
    concept: new FormArray(concept?.concept?.map(nestedConcept => initCodeSystemConceptForm(nestedConcept)) || []),
  });
};
```

The compiler is complaining that:

> Argument of type 'ICodeSystemConceptForm[]' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'AbstractControl<any, any>[]'.   Type
> 'ICodeSystemConceptForm' is missing the following properties from type
> 'AbstractControl<any, any>

I tried setting the FormArray in the interface as:

```js
concept: FormArray<FormGroup<ICodeSystemConceptForm>>
```

and:

```js
concept: FormArray<ICodeSystemConceptForm>
```

which results in:

> Type 'ICodeSystemConceptForm' does not satisfy the constraint
> 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.   Type 'ICodeSystemConceptForm' is
> missing the following properties from type 'AbstractControl<any,
> any>': _parent, _asyncValidationSubscription, value, validator, and 51
> more.ts(2344)

and also:

```js
concept: ICodeSystemConceptForm[];
```

but that results in the same error.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can we get a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I copied your code into the TS playground and am unable to continue due to `fhir4` not being defined.

Comment: @kelly I had an error elsewhere in my code that was causing issues with compilation. See my answer below for the correct format to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error elsewhere in my code that was causing compilation to fail. The correct way to represent the field is as such:

```js
concept: FormArray<FormGroup<ICodeSystemConceptForm>>;
```